# Use of BigDump.php giving errors while importing db

Tags: php, mysql, database

my Database is 145MB in size and i am using bigdump.php method to import it into my new site. firstly it gave me an error

```
$max_query_lines = 3000;
```

which gets solved when i changed the value from 300 to 3000 then error is solved but now it has imported only one table to my db and again giving this this error now  :

```
Error at the line 478: (443, 378, '', '', 'Roger', 'Stooke', '10 Asfordby Road', '', '10 Asfordby Road', NULL, 'LE13 0HR', 'Melton Mowbray', '', 222, 1);
```

i dont know what that means and how to solve it i have searched for it on net but didnt found anything useful. 
[image]

Comment: That statement looks fine but is only the first line of the file and the offending line 478. Maybe try dropping the max_query_lines a bit and see if that helps. Check the webserver error log for hints. Try looking in the file around line 478 (check a few before and a few after if need be) to see if there's a line with an un-escaped single quote or some other sort of problem. Maybe try uncompressing the file and uploading the .sql — I don't know BigDump but it's likely uncompressing the whole file in to memory which could cause it to hit the PHP resource limits.